# Redirect sub domain to another domain with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, digital-ocean

I need to redirect a sub domain (http://xxxxx.greetandcare.me/?mode=yyyyy) to another domain (https://anotherdomain.com/__/verify?mode=yyyyy)

- I tried to add NS, TXT, CNAME and A records to achieve this, but I was unable to apply the settings as these threw errors.

It would be great if there is a solution by redirecting it in the web browser when the URL is entered.

Comment: Also a working example would be great. I am still researching, but if anyone was able to crack this, I'll be happy!

Comment: Why is this tagged with Firebase? There's no correlation between redirecting a subdomain and Firebase.

Comment: That's for a reason of user authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the domain to Cloudflare to manage the DNS and created a page rule to achieve the need.

If the website is https://example.com/* then the page rule redirects it to https://othersite.com/$1

Here $1 is the content of *

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with DNS alone. You need to have a web server (e.g. Apache, nginx) responding to HTTP requests at your first domain which can forward requests through to your second domain.

If you're using AWS, Amazon S3 can do this via its [webpage redirect functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

Comment: If there is a script, I can host it. I have Digital Ocean hosting for my domain.

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan I'm afraid we need a little more information than that – if you're already running a web server on your Digital Ocean server (which I suspect you are) then you should be able to configure it to redirect from one domain to another based on the supplied hostname. Do you know what web server you're running? It will probably be either Apache or nginx.

Comment: LAMP it is. (sub.domain.com moves to domain.com/sub now)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can only redirect domain / subdomain to another domain. The parameters will be passed on as part of the redirect.

Comment: It's not the requirement. I think there are scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apache? then you can add this to your apache's .htaccess

RedirectMatch "^/?mode=yyyyy/?$" "https://anotherdomain.com/__/verify?mode=yyyyy"

See here for more info: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: Would try that.